# How To Determine Bottlenecks in a Computer

Tags: speed, components

This question is not for users trying to optimize a toaster, but instead for enthusiasts who build computers, and are looking for some idea of how much an upgrade to specific components may help.

Obviously, when running AMD Radeon software, a bottleneck is typically going to be the component running at 100% (except for VRAM, which I am to understand should run at 100% almost always). However, when running less intensive programs, it is less clear what is slowing things down.

My first example is the game League of Legends. None of my components exceed 30% (RAM, VRAM, CPU, SSD, nor GPU), yet the frames typically run at around 400 for the first 30 seconds of the game, then drop to about 200. This is a bit of an extreme example, but there are monitors with a refresh rate higher than 200 fps, so it could be problematic. My suspicion, however, is that the GPU software or perhaps Windows itself identifies that it is not worthwhile to generate a ridiculous number of frames if they're not being utilized, as my monitor's refresh rate is only 60 Hz (note I am in balanced as opposed to performance power settings on my desktop).

A second, more realistic example is the game portal 2: my SSD goes as high as 11% read speeds (as shown in task manager), nothing else exceeds 30% when loading the game, yet there is still about a 5 second wait for the level to load. Yes, 5 seconds is not that long (especially when it was a several minute wait on console). But, where is the source of this 5 second delay?

My question is: when the percentages in Task Manager and Radeon do not max out, how do we determine the component which is slowing down the computer the most?

The above two examples may not provide adequate motivation, but here is some: why would I upgrade to an M.2 NVMe drive when I can see my standard SATA SSD is never tasked beyond its capabilities? My suspicion with the Portal 2 example is that an NVMe drive would significantly boost load times, despite it being unclear how.

Comment: Time dependent drops in performance are usually indicators of thermal throttling, usually either in the CPU or GPU.

Comment: For both of your examples, I'd assume a single-threaded job is what's bottlenecking it.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best tools for this to get started is Resource Monitor (Windows Administrative Tools). Make sure the CPU line is expanded and you can expand the Description column to see the full description.

It is very good tool to get started with.

[image]

Another (and more advanced tool) once you have isolated something from the above is Process Monitor (Microsoft SysInternals).  This is a very detailed tool, so you would need an idea of the errant process to begin with and then filter for it in ProcMon.

[image]